# CKEditor adds {c} in front of the comments

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I am using the [ckeditor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-afterSetData) to edit email templates.

I am passing the `HtmlContent` to `setData`

```
editor.setData(htmlContent);
```

`editor` has the ckeditor instance.

At places in html content, there are these commented lines.

```
<![endif]--><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td>
```

which is getting converted into

```
<![endif]-->{C}<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td>
```

`{c}` is corrupting my template.

There is provision for call back function in `SetData` and also events such as `afterSetData()` but I could not prevent the `{c}` from corrupting my data.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: For the time being, I am using a hack in which I checked the 'minified js' file of **ckeditor** and removed `{C}` from 2 places where it was getting appended. At the moment it seems to work fine, but its just a hack and may give error for some other scenario.

Comment: Can you provide a working example, like JSFiddle? It's hard to tell whether it's a CKEditor bug or something weird going on with your data without the context.